# Plot graph for a cylinder

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, ipython

I am trying to plot a graph for a cylinder. Here are my functions for finding volume of the cylinder which is `v(r,h)= pi*r^2*h`. I don't know how to plot since this is my first attempt with python but these are my codes so far.

```
def compute_cylinder_area(r,h):
    h = float(h)
    pi = 3.14159
    surface_area = 2 * pi * r ** 2 + 2 * pi * r * h
    return surface_area
h=4
r =array([1,2,3,4,5])
r_new = 3
r_new = float(r_new)
print(compute_cylinder_area(r_new,h))
print(compute_cylinder_area(r,h))
```

How can I create a plot of radius(`x-axis`) versus cylinder volume (`y axis`) with the volume of cylinder with height `2,4` and `6` and the radius ranging from `0.0` to `10.0`. Also, how can I plot `3` volume curves as a function of radius on the figure?? I also need to label each curve and add axis label and a legend to the figure.

Comment: What have you tried? We are not going to do your homework for you. You can make nice graphs with matplotlib.pyplot for example. Lots of example and in the documentation...

Comment: Iterate across the values of r.

Comment: Standard x-y graphs are always described as the y variable vs. the x variable. Or the y variable as a function of the x variable.

Comment: Use an aggregator pattern to collect the volumes as you iterate. That means you initialize an aggregator to an empty list prior to a `for` loop, and each time through the loop, append to the aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a list of `x_values` and `y_values`, use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x_values, y_values)
fig.show()
```

You can also do this an interactive fashion to plot on the "active" axes, but the object-oriented approach shown here will be more effective in teaching you programming skills. Read more about the plot function at http://matplotlib.org/ where you can enter `plot` into the search box at the right and follow the link the method of an Axes: [matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot)

Comment: i dont understand. how can i do that?

Comment: what values do i assign to x and y ?

Comment: Your variable r contains a list of x values. To find y values, aggregate a list while iterating. See my comments to your original post. Another way is to use a generator. That's the preferred style for Python, but you should learn the basic loops first.